# removeAll seems to affect its argument

Tags: java, collections, removeall

I have written a generic Partition class (a partition is a division of a set into disjoint subsets, called parts). Internally this is a `Map<T,Integer>` and a `Map<Integer,Set<T>>`, where the Integers are the labels of the parts. For example `partition.getLabel(T t)` gives the label of the part that t is in, and `partition.move(T t, Integer label)` moves t to the partition labelled by label (internally, it updates both the Maps).

But my method for moving a Collection of objects to a new part does not work. It seems that Set.removeAll() is affecting its argument. I think the problem is something like a ConcurrentModificationException, but I can't work it out. Sorry the code is rather long, but I have marked where the problem is (about half-way down), and the output at the bottom should make it clear what the problem is - at the end the partition is in an illegal state.

```
    import java.util.*;

    public class Partition<T> {
  private Map<T,Integer> objToLabel = new HashMap<T,Integer>();
     private Map<Integer,Set<T>> labelToObjs = 
       new HashMap<Integer,Set<T>>();
     private List<Integer> unusedLabels;
     private int size;  // = number of elements

     public Partition(Collection<T> objects) {
      size = objects.size();
      unusedLabels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
       unusedLabels.add(i);
      // Put all the objects in part 0. 
      Set<T> part = new HashSet<T>(objects);
      for (T t : objects)
       objToLabel.put(t,0);
      labelToObjs.put(0,part);
     }

     public Integer getLabel(T t) {
      return objToLabel.get(t);
     }
     public Set<T> getPart(Integer label) {
      return labelToObjs.get(label);
     }
     public Set<T> getPart(T t) {
      return getPart(getLabel(t));
     }

     public Integer newPart(T t) { 
      // Move t to a new part. 
      Integer newLabel = unusedLabels.remove(0); 
      labelToObjs.put(newLabel,new HashSet<T>()); 
      move(t, newLabel); 
      return newLabel; 
     } 
     public Integer newPart(Collection<T> things) {
      // Move things to a new part. (This assumes that 
      // they are all in the same part to start with.)
      Integer newLabel = unusedLabels.remove(0);
      labelToObjs.put(newLabel,new HashSet<T>());
      moveAll(things, newLabel); 
      return newLabel; 
     }
     public void move(T t, Integer label) {
      // Move t to the part "label". 
      Integer oldLabel = getLabel(t);
      getPart(oldLabel).remove(t);
      if (getPart(oldLabel).isEmpty())  // if the old part is 
       labelToObjs.remove(oldLabel);  // empty, remove it
      getPart(label).add(t);
      objToLabel.put(t,label);
     }
     public void moveAll(Collection<T> things, Integer label) {
      // Move all the things from their current part to label. 
      // (This assumes all the things are in the same part.)
      if (things.size()==0)  return;

      T arbitraryThing = new ArrayList<T>(things).get(0);
      Set<T> oldPart = getPart(arbitraryThing);

   // THIS IS WHERE IT SEEMS TO GO WRONG //////////////////////////
      System.out.println(" oldPart = " + oldPart);
      System.out.println(" things = " + things);
      System.out.println("Now doing oldPart.removeAll(things) ...");
      oldPart.removeAll(things);
      System.out.println(" oldPart = " + oldPart);
      System.out.println(" things = " + things);

      if (oldPart.isEmpty())
       labelToObjs.remove(objToLabel.get(arbitraryThing));

      for (T t : things)
       objToLabel.put(t,label);
      getPart(label).addAll(things);
     }

     public String toString() {
      StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
      result.append("\nPARTITION OF " + size + " ELEMENTS INTO " + 
        labelToObjs.size() + " PART");
      result.append((labelToObjs.size()==1 ? "" : "S") + "\n");
      for (Map.Entry<Integer,Set<T>> mapEntry : 
        labelToObjs.entrySet()) {
       result.append("PART " + mapEntry.getKey() + ": ");
       result.append(mapEntry.getValue() + "\n");
      }
      return result.toString();
     }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> strings = 
        Arrays.asList("zero one two three".split(" "));

      Partition<String> p = new Partition<String>(strings);
      p.newPart(strings.get(3));  // move "three" to a new part
      System.out.println(p);

      System.out.println("Now moving all of three's part to the " + 
        "same part as zero.\n");
      Collection<String> oldPart = p.getPart(strings.get(3));
      //oldPart = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"three"});  // works fine!
      p.moveAll(oldPart, p.getLabel(strings.get(0)));
      System.out.println(p);
     }
    }

/* OUTPUT
PARTITION OF 4 ELEMENTS INTO 2 PARTS
PART 0: [two, one, zero]
PART 1: [three]

Now moving all of three's part to the same part as zero.

 oldPart = [three]
 things = [three]
Now doing oldPart.removeAll(things) ...
 oldPart = []
 things = []

PARTITION OF 4 ELEMENTS INTO 1 PART
PART 0: [two, one, zero]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Using my debugger I place a breakpoint before the removeAll and I can see (as I suspected) that oldPart and things as the same collection so removing all elements clears that collection.

Comment: Thank you. If anyone can easily see what I need to do to fix this class, I would be very grateful. I will try to work it out myself too.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is extremely confusing but as far as I can work out, `oldPart` and `things` are actually the same object. `Set.removeAll()` certainly doesn't affect its argument unless it is the same object as it's invoked on:

```
public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;

    if (size() > c.size()) {
        for (Iterator<?> i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); )
            modified |= remove(i.next());
    } else {
        for (Iterator<?> i = iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
            if (c.contains(i.next())) {
                i.remove();
                modified = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

**Update:**

The easy way to eliminate this is to use a copy of `things` in the `moveAll()` method. Indeed such a copy already exists.

```
T arbitraryThing = new ArrayList<T>(things).get(0);
```

This line creates but then instantly discards a copy of `things`. So I'd suggest replacing it with:

```
ArrayList<T> thingsToRemove = new ArrayList<T>(things)
T arbitraryThing = thingsToRemove.get(0);
```

And in the rest of the method, replace all references to `things` to `thingsToRemove`.

Comment: Thank you. Them being the same object would explain it. Could anyone suggest what I need to do to fix it? I would prefer not to make a copy of `things`. (Also sorry the code is confusing. Should I have put more comments, or is it just badly conceived or badly written?? I couldn't work out how to fix the indentation.)

Comment: @Edd Don't say sorry, it's your code, you're free to write it as you like. :) What confused me the most is that everything is a "part", "label" or "thing", all too generic words that give away very few hints about their purpose.  I'll update my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thank you. Awesome. I guess I used those words because it is an abstract mathematical object. There is probably a better word than "label", though.